# flutter error : ErrorDioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400]

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, dio

i have a widget that take attachment name and date picker with start date and end date and uploading button to upload attachment when i finish uploading and defining dates and click the button SAVE i get the masage with dio error responce,
what should i do?.

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
    Response response = await dio
        .post(BaseUrl + AppPaths.AddAttachments,
            data: formData,
            options: Options(
              method: 'POST',
              responseType: ResponseType.json,
              headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'},
            ))
        .then((value) {
      print({"response:" + value.toString()});
      if (value.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Done");
        print("response.statusCode");
        print(value.statusCode);
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });

        Navigator.pop(context);
      } else {
        print("Failed");
        print("response.statusCode");
        print(value.statusCode.toString());
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print("on Error" + onError.toString());
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

[picture with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I5c7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to test the API via Postman?

Code 400 means something went wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400